# how to create .keystore file for my java application inside eclipse

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, cloud, keystore

how to create .keystore file for my java application inside eclipse? I know methods to import ssl into keystore and place the same in jre/lib/security/cacerts folder. I want to deploy my application in cloud so i want the .keystore file to be in my code rather than my local system. Can you please guide me in this?

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understand your need, you can load the keystore using ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream as inputStream

You can read here

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

This could be an example

```
KeyStore myKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
InputStream keystoreInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/to/keystore/in/your/jar")
myKeyStore.load( keystoreInputStream , "yourpassword".toCharArray());
```